# why I cannot install self-made package from bitbucket?

Tags: r, r-package, cran, manifest.json, rsconnect

I am trying to install my own package created that appears on my company's bitbucket .

This is the warning I get :

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://bitbucket.astrazeneca.net/scm/ecos/flexmetrics.git/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bitbucket.astrazeneca.net/scm/ecos/flexmetrics.git/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://bitbucket.astrazeneca.net/scm/ecos/flexmetrics.git/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bitbucket.astrazeneca.net/scm/ecos/flexmetrics.git/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘/home/kkwf800/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file '/scratch/kkwf800/RtmpnVJJMr/miniCRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

I have tried approaches but not worked. First I have tried to follow the steps given at this link:

https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/custom-repos.html?_gl=114t201d_gaMTU0OTk5NTkwNS4xNjc0NzQzMTk0_ga_2C0WZ1JHG0*MTY4NDUwNTcxNC4xNS4xLjE2ODQ1MDcwMjYuMC4wLjA.

The same warning I get and yet it doesn't download it.

I have also tried this approach but again it doesn't work

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-introduction.html

As a background of what I am attempting to do. I have an flexdashboard page that I am trying to publish on rstudio connect. For this I need a manifest.json file which obviosly tells connect what packages I need for publishing my app.
However, when it comes to flexmetrics, because it is my own library, with the attempts I have undertaken, I've got this

```
[ "libs/flexmetrics/DESCRIPTION": {
      "checksum": "adadfcb3aa7a787b8b6d4cb1e6978496"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/help/aliases.rds": {
      "checksum": "2b1e3b75438e87da9ac0195f6573e465"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/help/AnIndex": {
      "checksum": "ce9f4e3e086ff6cf4a971ae1d86f32d7"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/help/flexmetrics.rdb": {
      "checksum": "37ecda9f859f044c2226471be4964fc6"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/help/flexmetrics.rdx": {
      "checksum": "3e59fd5d1d382c8b19e184c332ebbcfb"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/help/paths.rds": {
      "checksum": "c0e9c284891dc28a6076cfe670d9ba44"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/html/00Index.html": {
      "checksum": "7c6f7e43bd5850fd4a4a9d60907df2d4"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/html/R.css": {
      "checksum": "b6763e6916890c631fdc3f2643803b1a"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/INDEX": {
      "checksum": "60a11f831f4d841a8bb5a6c72397b282"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/Meta/features.rds": {
      "checksum": "d3a16df0a7280c65dbcca2baec44a3c2"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/Meta/hsearch.rds": {
      "checksum": "71c49eb4915bd2f0baa276743ea240f0"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/Meta/links.rds": {
      "checksum": "bfe41af4785332085fa810f0ca120e6c"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/Meta/nsInfo.rds": {
      "checksum": "a75396874cda7ce300cb4e47dd02833d"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/Meta/package.rds": {
      "checksum": "9744429edaca27586b0ac3e9b90d0239"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/Meta/Rd.rds": {
      "checksum": "6d3d4dd6a5a5f0d128adcbb01a04b709"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/NAMESPACE": {
      "checksum": "ced4311ec73e8880f7716a7fa0a9f0c0"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/R/flexmetrics": {
      "checksum": "d6c68f1fe41ced6e98a766a3757313da"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/R/flexmetrics.rdb": {
      "checksum": "fb764e43edce0a33b50d27e4507e1bcb"
    },
    "libs/flexmetrics/R/flexmetrics.rdx": {
      "checksum": "77b2253cb0a256cf50d16cef9d568b93"]
```

now, if I get to src/contrib - this what I have :

```
flexmetrics_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz file
PACKAGES
```

This is how PACKAGES looks like:

```
Package: flexmetrics
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Imports: config (>= 0.3.1), connectapi, dplyr, flexdashboard, forcats,
        ggplot2, golem (>= 0.3.5), gt, magrittr, plotly, shiny (>= 1.7.4),
        shinydashboard, shinydashboardPlus
Suggests: knitr, rmarkdown, spelling
License: MIT + file LICENSE
MD5sum: c1dd6a45dce597fe4f1d18e2c9de9da6
NeedsCompilation: no
```

I have this on my disc as well.

I am trying to understand why it doesn't download the library?